# setTimout within event handler

Tags: javascript, video, settimeout, video-player

I built an iFrame viewer for some videos [here](http://www.churchprojectionist.com/othervids.html).

It works pretty well, except when someone clicks on the button for video A and then clicks  video B's button while video A is still playing.  The viewer will close when video A would have finished and cuts video B off.

I have read a lot of questions and answers about using setTimeout inside of other functions.  I believe the problem is that setTimeout is taking the duration info from video A and not updating when video B is clicked, often referred to as a 'this' problem.

I have read a lot of questions and answers and tried a lot of solutions, but I can't make it work.  This is my first javascript project, so I'd appreciate your help very much.  Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
***
<body>
***
//The buttons contain data for the viewer, including the video's duration and the YouTube address.  This is a sample button:

<div id="MovieButtons" class="MovieButtons">
<button class="MovieButton" data-MovieId="Memorial" data-MovieDur="2740000"     data-MovieAdr="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sMVZbMxD-Xw?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;">Memorial Video</button>
        </div> <!--End Moviebuttons-->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery_3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

//initial state has the viewer hidden.  It appears when a movie is clicked.

$("#viewer").hide();

//declaring global variables -- the .val property will be assigned inside the function.

    var MovieId = {};
    var MovieDur = {};
    var MovieAdr = {};      

//When a movie is clicked, viewer gets its info from the button, 

    $(".MovieButton").on("click", function(){

    MovieId.val= $(this).attr("data-MovieId");
    MovieDur.val= Number($(this).attr("data-MovieDur"));
    MovieAdr.val= $(this).attr("data-MovieAdr");

//shows the viewer

    $("#viewer").show();

//viewer loads movie and plays

    $("#viewer").html("<iframe src="+oMovieAdr.val+" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" style=\"position:relative; left: 22%; top:0%; frameborder=\"1\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");

//Reset mechanism closes the viewport and hides the stop button, also restores normal page look.  This is where the problem is.

function reset(){
        $("#viewer").hide();
        $("#viewer").html("<iframe src= none></iframe>");
        };

//Automatically closes viewport when the movie ends.
    setTimeout(function(){
        reset();}, oMovieDur.val);

});     //end of $(".oMovieButton").on("click", function(){

}); //end of $(document).ready(function(){
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference,

Amadan's suggestion to shut one timer and start another was a good one, but the new timer was still using the original video duration within the event timer.  The solution I found was to use a jquery plugin by Ben Alman called doTimeout:  http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

I rewrote the timeout lines, originally:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    reset();}, oMovieDur.val);
```

as follows ('loop' is just an id):

```
$.doTimeout( 'loop', oMovieDur.val, function(){
reset();
});
```

and now things work properly.  Thanks to Amadan and Ben Alman

Answer (score 0):

A timer can't "update". If `oMovieDur.val` is `3600000`, you're passing `3600000` into `setTimeout`, not `oMovieDur.val` reference, and the timer will be triggering one hour later, whatever you later do to `oMovieDur`.

You should rather identify your timer, and shut it down if it is no longer relevant (i.e. you started a new movie and you're about to make a new timer).

```
var resetTimer = null;

// ...

clearTimeout(resetTimer);
resetTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        reset();}, oMovieDur.val);
```

Sample code:

```js
var timer = null;
$('button').click(function(evt) {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  console.log("started", name, "(ending in 3s)");
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log("aborted the previous", name);
  }
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    timer = null;
    console.log("ended", name);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-name="A">start A</button>
<button data-name="B">start B</button>
```

This demonstrates clearing the timer.

Comment: Thanks Amadan.  I tried this and had the same result, i.e. the value of resetTimer is still getting video A's duration from oMovieDur.val instead of video B's.  I need something like the jquery $.proxy method, but it only seems to operate on the first argument of setTimeout(callback,delay) not the delay.  Perhaps I could use .bind if I knew what it should attach to.

Comment: You can't get timer to update itself. `bind` can't help you, since `setTimeout` will not use a callback for its second argument, just a plain number. You have to cancel the timer and make a new one. I can't tell you why the code doesn't work: are you sure you put `resetTimer` in a high-enough context? It has to persist from one movie to the next.

Comment: Thanks again Amadan.  I've tried several locations for your suggested code (i.e. inside and outside the onClick event handler.  Certainly the Var goes outside, and I would think the rest goes inside, but that's not working for me.

Comment: I also tried trying to "proxify" oMovieDur.val= $(this).attr("data-oMovieDur"); for use as the duration in a setTimer statement.  Is that possible, or will setTimer only take a simple number as a duration?